# CSS loads perfectly when viewing file directly from my computer, but some CSS rules are not loading when the file is on the server

Tags: html, css

I am having a strange issue with HTML/CSS.

When I'm editing the files locally and checking my progress, everything works fine. However, when I send the files to the server and attempt to load the page there, some CSS rules are missing completely. The Firefox Inspector says "no css rules". The files themselves are identical, and they use relative links so the fact that the files are in a different location shouldn't affect anything.

The bizarre thing is that some of the CSS rules are working, but others aren't. Below is one of the elements that isn't working. Locally, the colours, floating etc. all work.

Here's one element that isn't working, alongside the HTML-file's head in case the problem is there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fi">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<link href="./tyyli.css" rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<title>ITKP1011</title>
</head>
<body>    

<div class="navigation">
    <ul class="navlist">
        <li><a href="./maecenas/">maecenas</a>
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href="./maecenas/porta/">porta</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="./faucibus/">faucibus</a>
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href="./faucibus/gravida/">gravida</a></li>
            <li><a href="./faucibus/proin/">proin</a></li>
            <li><a href="./faucibus/aliquam/">aliquam</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
        <li><a href="./nunc/">nunc</a>
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href="./nunc/dapibus/">dapibus</a></li>
            <li><a href="./nunc/sodales/">sodales</a></li>
            <li><a href="./nunc/cras/">cras</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS-file:

```
    body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
    
    display: flex;
    background-color: #73fcc3;

}

.flex-container > div {
background-color: #73fcc3;
padding: 7px;
margin: 0px;
}

.navigation {
    float: right;
    background-color: #73fcc3;
    border: 5px solid #55f7b3;
    padding-right: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navlist {
    padding-left: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to make sure that the CSS files really are being loaded: press F12 in the browser to get to the Developer Tools, find the "Network" tab, and look for any 404 responses.

Comment: Everything is working smoothly in the Network-tab.

Comment: In the Firefox dev tools' "Network" tab, there's checkbox for "Disable cache". Is that enabled? Sometimes caching means that an old copy of a file gets used by mistake. Another thing to try is a different browser, preferably one that hasn't visited the site before.

Comment: Oh, and remember to have a peek in the "Console" tab every now and again in case it sneaks a useful error message in there for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lied in the cache. I didn't realize it had to be reloaded. I did it by pressing Shift + F5, and everything works again.